# Aptana Studio messed up my default editor settings in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aptana

Since I installed the 'stand-alone' Aptaba Studio, my Eclipse wants to open certian files, e.g. "MSG.utf", in Aptana Studio.
Note that I never installed the Aptaba Plugin.
And even after uninstalling Aptana as documented (i.e. just moving the Application Folder to the trash, in OS X), the settings are noct changed back. Instead, Eclipse now does not open these files at all anymore. So:

1) Why has Aptana Studio messed up my Eclipse settings?

2) What other file types /Ednings and other settings might be affected?

3) How can I change this back to normal/before?

Answer (score 0):

Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations

Here you can set which file types open with which editors, internal and external, and also set defaults.

Try modifying the entry/adding an entry of utf files with the editor you want to open.

Answer (score 0):

Install this plug-in: http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/update and you, Aptana and your Eclipse layouts will forever be happy!